# Migrating from Mercurial to Subversion

Tags: svn, version-control, mercurial, version-control-migration

> **Possible Duplicate:**
>   [Converting from Mercurial to Subversion](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/1898994/converting-from-mercurial-to-subversion)

Hi.

Does anyone know of a relatively painless way to migrate a Mercurial repo to a fresh Subversion repo?

Thank you.

Comment: Of course, the snarky unhelpful question is "Why would you want to?".  Unfortunately, I don't have a really good answer as Subversion has a really different notion of branch than Mercurial does.

Comment: I want to use some of Subversion's IDE integration powers with RubyMine, that Mercurial and Git don't support.  I'd prefer Git, but the IDE integration is ultimately more useful to me.

Comment: Curious indeed.. usually people are moving in the opposite direction.

Answer (score 7, accepted):

You may want to use the [Convert Extension](http://mercurial.selenic.com/wiki/RepositoryConversion).

```
hg convert --dest-type svn mercurial_repo_name svn_repo_name
```

This extension is distributed with Mercurial and understands CVS, Subversion, Git, Darcs, Monotone, Bazaar, GNU Arch, Perforce and Mercurial as source formats and Mercurial and Subversion as destination formats.

Comment: I tried running this at the command line and Mercurial doesn't recognize the command... hmmm...

Comment: @Alex: Did you enable the extension?

Comment: Yes, make sure it is enabled in your .hgrc file.

Answer (score 2):

Use [hgsubversion](http://bitbucket.org/durin42/hgsubversion/wiki/Home)?