# Converting mercurial repository to svn repository

Tags: svn, version-control, mercurial, repository

I know you can convert svn repository to mercurial repository (or use mercurial as a client to svn repo)
but what I want is to convert mercurial repository to svn repository.

We have some tool that uses SVNKit, and we'd like to continue use it, but want to be able to work on mercurial repository. Hence we want to completely convert mercurial repo to svn repo.
Is that something that's possible? (and how?)

Comment: Sblom, I think I know what you mean.

Answer (score 2):

Consider using [hgsubversion](http://bitbucket.org/durin42/hgsubversion/wiki/Home) which lets you work on a svn repo from within mercurial, which it sounds like is your real goal.

Alternately you can use the 'convert' command inside mercurial to do the convert:

```
hg convert --dest-type svn mercurialpath subversionpath
```

where convert has some options you can find with `hg help convert` that will affect the outcome.

Answer (score 1):

Perhaps [Tailor](http://progetti.arstecnica.it/tailor/) can help?

[Another question](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/2106204/migrating-from-mercurial-to-subversion) suggests Mercurial's [ConvertExtension](http://mercurial.selenic.com/wiki/RepositoryConversion). I thought that was strictly for *importing to* Mercurial, but [apparently not](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/2106204/migrating-from-mercurial-to-subversion/2106234#2106234).