# Converting a Mercurial (hg) repository to Subversion (svn)

Tags: svn, version-control, mercurial, repository, version-control-migration

I need to convert an existing Mercurial repository to Subversion, I tried with the following command:

```
hg convert --dest-type svn mercurialpath subversionpath
```

That I took from the following topics:

[Converting mercurial repository to svn repository](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/2570520/converting-mercurial-repository-to-svn-repository)

[Migrating from Mercurial to Subversion](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/2106204/migrating-from-mercurial-to-subversion)

The problem is that after launching this command the conversion starts and ends apparently successfully but I only get a "working copy" directory in the PWD and in the subversionpath a folder with semi-empty files and directory as "db", "lock", etc...
I don't have an idea of how I can solve this problem. Thanks

Comment: In the title you say to convert from hg to svn but in contradiction to the message itself where you say to convert from svn to hg ? So now what do you really mean ?

Comment: You're totally right, gwhitake already fixed it, thanks.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

> and in the subversionpath a folder with semi-empty files and directory as "db", "lock", etc.

That sounds like a description of the Subversion repository.  You won't see your source files in there in any readable format.  Each revision is kept in a file in the directory structure under the dev/revs folder but in a binary diff format.

Comment: But I do not understand why the source code that is contained in the repository is placed somewhere else. What's the meaning of the working copy folder?

Comment: @Raffo: The way subversion works is that there is a central repository containing all of the revision information but you actually work in a "working copy".  Doing a commit sends all your changes in the working copy to the central repository.  If you are not familiar with how Subversion works, I suggest you read at least this chapter of the SVN book. http://svnbook.red-bean.com/en/1.7/svn.basic.html